# Find path of a file which is not in the current directory and access the files in that folder one by one - Python

Tags: python, csv, file, path, operating-system

I have 2 questions here.

1. My goal is to access multiple .csv files in a folder. I know the folder name and it is not in the current directory. How to find the path of that folder?
2. Once I find the path of that folder, how can I iterate through the .csv files in that folder?
   P.S: I don't want to open the .csv files.

I just want to find the folder and then I want to load the .csv files found in that folder to some other location.
Note: I am using macOS

Answer (score 0):

Probably os.walk is the way to go.  Something like:

```
import os 

target_folder = 'I_know_this_folder_name'
csvs = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('c:'):  #Substitute '/' for 'c:' if using Mac or linux
    for dirname in dirs:
        if dirname == target_folder:
            for filename in files:
                if filename.lower().endswith('csv'):
                    full_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
                    csvs.append(full_path)

print(csvs)
```

If, as you say, you want every csv that is within the target folder, you could try the following (but note it will include csvs within ANY folder of the same name):

```
import os 

target_folder = 'I_know_this_folder_name'
csvs = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('c:'):  #Substitute '/' for 'c:' if using Mac or linux
    for dirname in dirs:
        if target_folder in root:
            for filename in files:
                if filename.lower().endswith('csv'):
                    full_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
                    csvs.append(full_path)

print(csvs)
```

Comment: I want to access the files inside target_folder. But the above solution is giving me csv files which are present in the target_folder location and not the folders inside it.
Ex: Desktop/target_folder
       csvs is having the path for the csv files which are present on Desktop and not for the target_folder